# Django: Get names of fields of a model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a method that returns the names of fields of a model class. I want the method to return a list of field names, like this: `["first_name", "middle_name", "last_name", "gender"]`.

I have tried this:

```
@classmethod
def get_fields_for_form(cls):
    fields = cls._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)

    return [field.__class__.__name__ for field in fields]
```

But the result I get is not what I want: `["AutoField", "ForeignKey", "CharField"]`

How can I get the name of the fields of a model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly modify your method:

```
@classmethod
def get_fields_for_form(cls):
    fields = cls._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
    return [field.name for field in fields]
```

But for what purpose you are doing this?
E.g. If you need django form you can create forms from models using ModelForm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: The reason why I am doing this is that I am not using Django Forms. I am building a system with a backend REST API with Django Rest Framework, and a web frontend with ReactJS. I want the frontend to be highly dynamic and reactive to the data it is interacting with, so I am loading some data description  to the frontend, which is basically agnostic of the data, so it can configure itself.